# How to call a method defined in an Activity class from a (non-activity) Java class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my DataTrak activity I defined the following method:

```
    public void updateTotal(IAmount totalAmount, int transactionType) {
        switch (transactionType) {
            case AccountTotals.VALUE_CANCELS:
                txtView_cancels_value.setText("" +     (Long.parseLong(txtView_cancels_value.getText().toString()) + totalAmount.getValue()));          
                break;
            case AccountTotals.VALUE_PAYS:
                txtView_pays_value.setText("" + (Long.parseLong(txtView_pays_value.getText().toString()) + totalAmount.getValue()));            
                break;
            case AccountTotals.VALUE_SALES:
                txtView_sales_value.setText("" + (Long.parseLong(txtView_sales_value.getText().toString()) + totalAmount.getValue()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
    btn_total.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_green );

}
```

The method computes and updates some TextViews and changes the color of a button. Then I need to call this method from a Java abstract class. The method call appears in a method that runs on a non-UI thread. Here's how I call the method:

```
            new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new DataTrak().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {           
                        new DataTrak().updateTotal(totalAmount,transactionType);
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
```

The problem is that I get a run time exception. Here's the LogCat output:

```
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1577
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101): Process: com.ilts.lct, PID: 22101
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101):    at android.os.Handler.<init>    (Handler.java:200)
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:786)
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101):    at com.ilts.lct.ap.mainframe.DataTrak.<init>(DataTrak.java:37)
05-13 16:52:13.325: E/AndroidRuntime(22101):    at com.ilts.lct.ap.customerfunctions.CustomerTransaction$2.run(CustomerTransaction.java:736)
```

In fact, initially I had just the line with the method call but I got the same run time exception. I searched for  "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" and I found several posts on this issue. One of them made me put the method call inside a new Thread, as shown above. But I still get the same run time exception. What should I change? Could you help me understand what's the problem actually and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

After I read the answer by @Metero here's the code in the Java abstract class:

```
public abstract class CustomerTransaction extends Transaction {
...................................................

    public interface CallBack {
    public void updateTotal(IAmount a,int n);
}

private static CallBack callback;

public static void registerCallback(CallBack callback1){
   callback = callback1;
}

/**
 * Method to update the transaction state
 *
 * @param  state  The new transaction state
 **/
public void setState(final int state) {
    this.state = state;
    /*
     * Update the status
     */
    if (state == TRANSACTION_COMPLETE) {
                    new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                new DataTrak().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("HERE", "HERE");
                        Looper.prepare(); 
                        callback.updateTotal(totalAmount,transactionType);
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();

   }
   }
....................
}
```

Comment: Does DataTrak create the other class?

Comment: What do you mean by "create" here? I'm not sure what to answer, because I don't understand the question. But I can tell you that there  is no object of the other class in the DataTrak activity.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which class instantiates the non-activity class? i.e. does the activity have any reference to the non-activity object? But from reading your reply it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right: The non-activity class is instatiated by some other classes, but not by DataTrak.

Answer (score 1):

You should never instantiate an Activity by yourself, if you do that, it won't be a normal activity, it will be just a problematic plan Java object.

So what you can maybe to to solve your problem is use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) where you can define an interface with the 'callback' method and you let the Activity implement it and make it subscribe to the 'provider' of the notification. So basically, when this update Thread is running, you will run thru the list of subscribed listeners and dispatch the call, it will be just like a normal method call.

Just keep in mind to: 'subscribe' and 'unsubscribe' respecting the Activity lifecycles..like subscribe on onCreate() and unsubscribe on onDestroy().

Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements ControlListener {

public void onCreate(...) {
 ....
 control.registerListener(this);

 control.performOperation();

}

public void onDestroy(...) {
 ....
 control.unregisterListener(this);
}

public void updateTotal(String newValue) {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     textView.setText(newValue);
   } 
  });

   }
  }
```

Control class:

```
   public class Control {

      private Set<ControlListener> listeners = new HashSet<ControlListener>();

     public synchronized void registerListener(ControlListener listener) {
       listeners.add(listener);
     }

    public synchronized void unRegisterListener(ControlListener listener) {
       listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public synchronized void notifyListeners(String newValue) {
      for(ControlListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.updateTotal(newValue);
      }
    }

     public void performOperation() {

      new Thread() {
        public void run() { 
          String newValue= service.performBackgroundOperationToGetNewValue();

         notifyListeners(newValue);
        }
      }.start();
     }
   }
```

Control listener:

```
 public interface ControlListener {
    public void updateTotal(String newValue);
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use a very HANDY library to apply the Observer pattern on your project, it's the **Otto**: http://square.github.io/otto/   With the Otto, you wouldn't need to have the register/unregister/notifylisteners methods in your control, it would be placed somewhere else automatically.

Comment: I changed the code and used the observer pattern based on this [example](http://www.ootpapps.com/2013/02/android-observers-and-observables-how-to-update-activities-automatically-upon-data-changes/) but I don't get the TextViews updated. What could be wrong when I have 1 observer registered (found this using countObservers() in the Activity class) but when I check this in the class that extends Observable I have zero observers? The second question: what is the callback method that you mentioned above? Do I need one if I use the Observer pattern? Thank you in advance.

Comment: the callback method is basically the 'updateTotal' on your case. The method that will be called when the event happens. So in your case, what i think you need to do is just call the updateTotal() directly from the Thread, without doing the new DataTrak().runOnUiThread()..this is the wrong part. That thread shouldn't know what is DataTrak..that is the goal of using Observer, to leave these components loosely coupled. So, with that, as the updateTotal() will be called from a non-UI-Thread..then inside the updateTotal() implementation you do the runOnUiThread() putting that 'switch case' in it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did add runOnUiThread() inside updateTotal() but I still get zero observers when I notify the registered observers. So this means there are no more observers. Why?

Comment: @Monica make sure your calling the method that registers the callback, if you're doing that, the observers should not be empty. When the observer is an activity, to be compliant with the Activity life cycle, we do register on the onCreate()  and unregister on the onDestroy(). So if you are doing this and still is can't understand what's going on, then it's probably a synchronization issue: make the all access to the observers is synchronized, in other words, the register/unregister and get observers list should be synchronized methods.it will ensure their changes are visible for other threads.

Comment: In your case you have the operations Register observer being called from the Uithread and the notify observers from the new Thread, so the new thread won't see the changes made by the other thread if it isn't synchronized, or if the field variable isn't 'volatile' (if your dealing with a single field, not a list).

Comment: I tried to understand and follow your suggestions. In my activity class I declared "synchronized" the following methods: updateTotal() and a method that adds the observer and counts the number of observers. In the class that extends Observable I declared "synchronized" the method that notifies the observers. No progress so far: the TextView in updateTotal() is not updated. In fact, the class that extends Observable does not do this directly, because for some reasons it extends another (abstract) class. This abstract super class is the one that extends Observable. Does this make any difference?

Comment: Should I use java.util.Observable or android.database.Observable<T> ?

Comment: hi @Monica, i've updated the answer with some code..basically the Observer pattern is applied, but using the 'Listener' terminology.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. What should contain the ControlListener  interface? The class Control is the same class as the one where I have the method that computes the new value used to update the TextView?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the definition of the ControlListener interface. Yes, the Control class represents the class that you previously were calculating the new value, the one with a new Thread in it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am left with writing the service, but now I have to work on something else (it's a work related project). But I am going to +1 your response because I tested it with a "hardcoded" value and it worked. I'll come back to this problem, however, to solve it completely.

Comment: Alécio I am back working to completely solve this issue. I realized however that it looks like in your sample code you are using the result (newValue) from running a service (see your sample code in Control class, method performOperation.) Now I need an activity to start such a service. And I need to start it when I have available the value, which is in some method of the Control class. But Control is not an activity. Could you please help me understand? What am I missing here? Where should I start the service?

Comment: if you're referring to 'service.performBackgroundOperationToGetNewValue();'  it doesn't necessarily mean it is a Service (from Android) but a service class fro your code...it can be just another control class that fetches the data. OK? You can actually put the 'fetching data code' inline there.

Comment: Alecio, I have been working on and off this problem but it is still unsolved. I understood your previous comment, and I tried to use it. Now the issue is that when I try to notify the listeners to update the new value, the set of listeners is empty. I guess I should show my code as it is now, but probably I should ask a different question, based on the current situation. Still, if you can make a guess about why I get an empty set of listeners, please let me know.

Comment: You are subscribing the listeners on the onCreate() and unsubscribing them on the onDestroy() if the activity isn't being destroyed, the listeners should be available..so not empty. Another thing, if my any means you forgot to put the 'synchronized' on the register/unregister methods as well as on the notifyListeners you might have thread visibility problem..so the data is there, but the Thread that is using the notifyListeners doesn't see them. Make sure you synchronize the changes and usages of the listeners, like in the Control class in the example.

Comment: Thank you, Alecio. Even if I comment out the unsubscribing in onDestroy() I get an empty set of listeners. I didn't forget to synchronize the register/unregister methods. I just posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520573/why-is-the-set-of-listeners-empty-when-i-need-them-to-be-notified-in-an-androi

Answer (score 1):

The very nature of this question suggests a MVC violation.  Instead of your model calling methods in an Activity, it should call a method on some callback that the Activity has registered on the model.  This callback should be queued in the UI thread.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? For instance what do you mean by "call a method on some callback that the Activity has registered on the model"?

Comment: The searchable term is "observer pattern".  Say your model was in a class called `Account`.  You might create an interface called `AccountChangeListener` with a method `onBalanceChanged()`.  Your activities would register listeners on an instance of `Account`.  Then whenever the balance changes, the `Account` calls `onBalanceChanged()` on all its listeners, queueing the calls in the UI thread if that is part of its contract.  `Account` itself remains totally agnostic of the UI or anything else affected by the fact that the data changed.

Comment: BTW, the "official" Android way of implementing the observer pattern is using `BroadcastReceiver`, but sometimes that's more trouble than it's worth.  The android-async-http library is a good example of using the observer pattern without `BroadcastReceiver`.  It defines its own callback interface for observing the success or failure of a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best choice.

```
new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new DataTrak().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Looper.prepare();//This is not the best choice.
                    new DataTrak().updateTotal(totalAmount,transactionType);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
```

I recommend use AsyncTask, like this.

```
class SampleTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> {

    private int totalAmount;
    private yourActivity activity;

    //passing parameters
    public void SampleTask(yourActivity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        while (totalAmount < 10){
            totalAmount++;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
// this is not the best choice
// because you are creating two instances.
        new DataTrak().updateTotal(totalAmount,transactionType);

        //If you pass a parameter, this for me is the best option.

        activity.updateTotal(totalAmount,transactionType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried first the non-recommended solution and if I add one other Looper.prepare() then I get no more errors. I am trying to understand the second solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good, if you want understand AsyncTask, I recommend this link
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
In Spanish,
http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=3099

Answer (score 0):

I agree @Alécio, please use a callback to do this. Add a callback interface in the non-activity class:

```
   class yourclass{
        public interface callBack{
               public void updateTotal(...);
         }

        private callBack callback;

        public void registerCallback(callBack callback){
              this.callback = callback;
        }

        //somewhere call the updateTotal(...)
        callback.updateTotal(...);
  }
```

In the Activity

```
  //the activity implement the callback and then register it, and call the callback when neccesary

    class yourActivity extends Activity implement callBack{

        @Override
        onCreate(...){
        ...

        yourclass.registerCallback(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void updateTotal(...){
         .......
        }

    }
```

The sample code for multiple class comunicating.

```
public class Controller {
    callBack callBack;

    public void registerCallBack(callBack back){
        this.callBack = back;
    }

    public void show(){
          callBack.update(1, "my name");
    }

    public interface callBack{
        public void update(int type, String message);
    }

    public callBack getCallBack(){
        return callBack;
    }

}
```

```
public class AnotherClass {
    Controller controller = new Controller();

    public void registerCallBack(callBack back){
        controller.registerCallBack(back);
    }

    public void show(){
        controller.getCallBack().update(1, "show me!");
    }

}
```

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements callBack {
    AnotherClass myclass = new AnotherClass();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        Log.d("TAG", "This is message!"); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myclass.registerCallBack(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myclass.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(int type, String message) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.display)).setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helping code. What is actually public     registerCallback(callBack callback) ? Is it a void type method?

Comment: Oops,I have changed the return type.

Comment: I used your code but I get an exception "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." Then I tried to call updateTotal(...) on the UI like this '         new Thread()
         {
             public void run() {
                 Looper.prepare();
                 new DataTrak().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                 {
                     public void run() {
                         Looper.prepare();      
                      callback.updateTotal(totalAmount,transactionType);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }.start();'

Comment: The problem with the above solution is that nothing happens: the TextViews are not updated, but there is no run time exception.

Comment: I tested it, there is no problem when call the function contains callback.updteTotal(...)(such as show(){ callback.updateTotal(...)}). Is that you create another instance of java class("yourclass")? Since you should have createed it in the onCreat() of the activity, and you should just use that instance.

Comment: I suggest that get data from the thread, once the data is ready, then call the callback.updateTotal(...).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I don't quite understand it. I have to add that the Java class (which you call "yourclass") is an abstract class. So I changed the callback variable and the registerCallBack function to be static. Then in the activity class I call the method registerCallback exactly as in your code.

Comment: Yes, I posted the code from the Java class in the body of my question, at the end.

Comment: I think the static method is the problem, you'd better get the CustomerTransaction instance in the Activity(directly or from another class, keep it unique), then call the register the callback, toggle the updateTotal from where you use the same instance of the CustomerTransaction.

Comment: But I can't have an instance of CustomerTransaction because it is an abstract class.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I see in the AnotherClass that you write some "hardcoded" int and string using the method call controller.getCallBack().update(1, "show me!");   Now my problem is to adapt your sample code to write the data I get in the CustomerTransaction class.

Comment: It looks like AnotherClass in your code should be my CustomerTransaction class in my project. Is this correct? But then I still have to instantiate CustomerTransaction (which is abstract) in the activity class. And by the way, perhaps you intended to delete the first version of activity and leave only MyActivity from your code.

Comment: What I tried to do is to make AnotherClass extend CustomerTransaction and use your sample code, but I still don't get the TextView updated. Something is wrong but I don't know what. It appears that in my project the method updateTotal defined in DataTrak activity is never called.

Comment: please take a look at your sample code. How do you make sure that in Controller class the method getCallBack() does not return null? Where (when) do you set callBack?

Comment: Yes, it maybe null, you need to regiter it first, and make it not null. Maybe you can add some log to trace you code, to see what is going wrong.