# Why is the set of listeners empty when I need them to be notified? (in an Android app)

Tags: java, android, listener

In my Android app I have three classes, one is the MainActivity another one is called CustomerTransaction, which is just a Java class. There is also another activity called DataActivity which starts when the button Enter Data on the MainActivity screen is clicked. The activity DataActivity allows the user to enter a number in an EditText and then click the Send button to trigger a method in CustomerTransaction. I shall add the complete code below. But first let me explain my problem. In CustomerTransaction I have a method that provides values for two variables: totalAmount and transactionType (both are int). This values are needed in the MainActivity to be displayed on the main screen, when they are available. The MainActivity implements an interface called CustomListeners containing the header of the function that displays the two values (in TextViews). The values are communicated from CustomerTransaction to the method in MainActivity by notifying the listener when the values are available. The problem is that when I have the values, the set of listeners is empty. I would like to understand why this happens and then to correct the code.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.customlistenertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CustomListeners {
TextView tv_amount;
TextView tv_transactionType;
Button btn_enterData;
CustomerTransaction control= new CustomerTransaction();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    control.registerListener(this);

    tv_amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_amount);
    tv_transactionType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_transactionType);
    btn_enterData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enterData);

    addListenerOnButtonEnterData();
}

public void addListenerOnButtonEnterData() {
    btn_enterData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent intent = 
new Intent(MainActivity.this,com.example.customlistenertest.DataActivity.class);       
startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });

}

public void updateTotal(final int transactionType, final int totalAmount) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    tv_amount.setText(Integer.toString(totalAmount));
    tv_transactionType.setText(Integer.toString(transactionType));
   }});
}

@Override    
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
 public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    control.registerListener(this);
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
 }

@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     control.unregisterListener(this);
 }

} // End MainActivity
```

Following is the code for the DataActivity class:

```
package com.example.customlistenertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv_enterNumber;
EditText et_number;
Button btn_send;
CustomerTransaction transaction;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enter_data);

    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_number);
}

public void send(View view) {
    transaction = new CustomerTransaction();
    transComplete();
}

private void transComplete() {
    new Thread("TransComplete") {
        public void run() {
            String s_number = et_number.getText().toString();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(s_number);
            transaction.setState(5, value);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
} // end DataActivity
```

Following is the code for the CustomerTransaction class:

```
package com.example.customlistenertest;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CustomerTransaction {
public static final int DATA_ENTERED = 1;
public static final int TRANSACTION_COMPLETE = 5;
private int state;
private int totalAmount;
private int transactionType;
public Set<CustomListeners> listeners = new HashSet<CustomListeners>();


public synchronized void registerListener(CustomListeners listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public synchronized void unregisterListener(CustomListeners listener) {
       listeners.remove(listener);
}

public synchronized void notifyListeners() {
   for(CustomListeners listener : listeners) {
 if (totalAmount != 0)
    listener.updateTotal(transactionType,totalAmount);
else
    listener.updateTotal(transactionType,0);
   }
}

public void performOperation() {

  new Thread("MyThread") {
   public void run() { 
    notifyListeners();
 }
 }.start();
}    
public void setState(final int state, final int value) {
   this.state = state;
   this.totalAmount = value;
   this.transactionType = 999;
   if (state == DATA_ENTERED) {

   }
   if (state == TRANSACTION_COMPLETE) {
        performOperation();
   }
 }

} // end CustomerTransactionjava
```

I shall add the two layout files as well. The first is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_transactionType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_enterData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Data" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The next one is the file enter_data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_enterNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter a number:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >
    <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="send"
    android:text="Send" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Finally, here's the Manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.customlistenertest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application 
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.customlistenertest.DataActivity" >    
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "the set of listeners is empty"?

Comment: @codeMagic Eventhough I need only one listener, I use a HashSet to add the listeners to it, in order to register the listener. See the code in ClassA. Using the debugger I can see that this set is empty when I call want to notify the listener(s0. So there is no listener to notify, although previously I can see that the litener is added to the HashSet. Did I answer your question?

Comment: `if (totalAmount != null)` <- That won't even compile because `totalAmount` is an int.  Post your real code or reduce it to a SSCCE.  You'll probably answer your own question in the process.

Comment: Yes, I tried to simplify the code. In fact totalAmount is an object and it has an int variable. I shall edit the code.

Comment: Why exactly do you expect your current code to work? Right now, your two activities `MainActivity` and `DataActivity` **each** has its own `CustomTransaction` object meaning that the listeners you register will only apply to that object(which doesn't affect the other activity). You may want to look into making the `CustomTransaction` class as a singleton so it shares its state between the two activities.

Comment: I know what a singleton is, but I don't understand why the two activities each has a different CustomerTransaction object. I only instantiate it in the MainActivity.

Comment: Oh, I think I missed the CustomerTransaction class variable in the DataActivity.

Comment: `MainActivity` has the `control` object. `DataActivity` has the `transaction` object that you instantiate with `transaction = new CustomerTransaction();`.

Comment: Thank you @Luksprog, your answer was very useful. However I chose to use static methods versus Singleton, because in my real app it would be complicated to make the class a singleton.

Comment: You should never make activity references static because you risk leaking them.

Comment: I used static variables and methods in a non-activity Java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "CustomerTransaction transaction" used in the MainActivity is not the same instance of the  "CustomerTransaction transaction" of the one defined in the DataActivity. That explains why the DataActivity one is empty, because you did subscribe only with the one from the MainActivity. Two possible solutions for the problem:

1. Make the 'control' a singleton, so that you will be sure that there is only one instance of it at a time.
2. Make the 'listeners' variables and the 'register/unregister/notitifylisteners' methods static.

I prefer the option 1, but you can choose what you think it's best.

Good luck!